# I can't get "else if " part of the code in java-script for form-validation

Tags: javascript, simple-html-dom

I am doing a login form ,where, if the input fields is empty I want to declare an error message. I am only getting the 'if' part of the code but not the 'else if' part.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('fname');
var b = document.getElementById('pwd');
var c = document.getElementById('demo1');
var d = document.getElementById('demo2');

function func() {
  if (a.value == null || a.value == "") {
    c.innerHTML = 'Fields can\'t be empty';
    a.style.border = "2px solid red";
    return false;
  } else if (b.value == null || b.value == "") {
    d.innerHTML = "Password should be minimum 6 character";
    b.style.border = "2px solid red";
    return false;
  } else {
    true
  }

}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return func()">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="first name"><br><br>
  <p id="demo1" style="color: red;"></p>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id='pwd' placeholder='password'><br><br>
  <p id="demo2" style="color: red;"></p>
  <button type="submit" id="smbt"> sumbit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: return false will not execute further code it will get out from the function. Basically as per your code you will get one error at a time

Comment: The `else if` block executes only if the `if` one doesn't. If you want to show both error messages when both fields are empty, you cannot use `else if`; you need two separate `if`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it's not working. if there is a value in the "fname" field and the "pwd" is left blank, your code does show the message to enter 6+ char password.

Comment: @CodingOtaku Rameez wants to show all the errors for the empty inputs. However, he has used else if so it won't work simultaneously for all fields.

Comment: By the way, your function is not checking whether the password has minimum 6 characters; it just checks that the password is not empty but would accept even a single character.

Comment: Finally, unless you are doing it somewhere else in the code, you are not resetting the styles when the input is amended therefore if you leave the `fname` field empty, then submit, then type something in field, it will still display the error message and the red border.

Comment: i second that @secan.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code hope it helps.

```
function func() {
    var IsValid = true;
    if (a.value == null || a.value == "") {
        c.innerHTML = 'Fields can\'t be empty';
        a.style.border = "2px solid red";
        IsValid = false;
    }
    if (b.value == null || b.value == "") {
        d.innerHTML = "Password should be minimum 6 character";
        b.style.border = "2px solid red";
        IsValid = false;
    }
    return IsValid;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = document.getElementById('fname');
var b = document.getElementById('pwd');
var c = document.getElementById('demo1');
var d = document.getElementById('demo2');

function func() {

  if (a.value == null || a.value == "") {
    c.innerHTML = 'Fields can\'t be empty';
    a.style.border = "2px solid red";
   }
  if (b.value == null || b.value == "") {
    d.innerHTML = "Password should be minimum 6 character";
    b.style.border = "2px solid red";
   }



  if (a.value == null || a.value == "") {
    return false;
  } else if (b.value == null || b.value == "") {
    return false;
  } else {
    true
  }

}
```

HTML :

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return func()">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="first name"><br><br>
  <p id="demo1" style="color: red;"></p>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id='pwd' minlength="6" placeholder='password'><br><br>
  <p id="demo2" style="color: red;"></p>
  <button type="submit" id="smbt"> sumbit</button>
</form>
```

Use something like that - it will dislay both messages if you leave empety login and password. And HTML include 6 chars in your password.

You need to use minlength="6" in your input attribute just.

Comment: It is not an issue of `==` vs `===`; the issue is that an `else if` block would never execute if the preceding `if` block does... which is the very aim of an `else if` block. Furthermore the `return` statements will interrupt the execurion

Comment: Now it would work, but could be slightly simplified (e.g. like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eLtky6uf/))

Answer (score 1):

Also quoting @vaibhav 's ans. I would add extra functionality by setting the min lenght of the  password to 6. Also I added some conditions to prevent edge cases as explained in comments

```js
var a = document.getElementById('fname');
var b = document.getElementById('pwd');
var c = document.getElementById('demo1');
var d = document.getElementById('demo2');

   function func() {
  var IsValid = true;
  c.innerHTML ="";                    // if you got the name empty the first time and 
  a.style.border = "2px solid green"; //then corrected the name and got the passwprd wrong, */
  d.innerHTML ="";                    // both the name and the pass would be in red. 
  b.style.border = "2px solid green"; // Also the reason for setting the `innerHTML =""`

  
    if (a.value == null || a.value == "") {
        c.innerHTML = 'Fields can\'t be empty';
        a.style.border = "2px solid red";
        IsValid = false;
    }              //    */

    if (b.value.length < 6) {          // min lenght of password
        d.innerHTML = "Password should be minimum 6 character";
        b.style.border = "2px solid red";
        IsValid = false;
    }
    return IsValid;
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return func()">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="first name" ><br><br>
  <p id="demo1" style="color: red;"></p>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id='pwd' placeholder='password' ><br><br>
  <p id="demo2" style="color: red;"></p>
  <button type="submit" id="smbt"> sumbit</button>
</form>

<!-- with the required attribute in input tag a user would not be able to keep them empty in this case.

<form action="" onsubmit="return func()">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="first name" required><br><br>
  <p id="demo1" style="color: red;"></p>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id='pwd' placeholder='password' required><br><br>
  <p id="demo2" style="color: red;"></p>
  <button type="submit" id="smbt"> sumbit</button>
</form>

-->
```